# Customize Revenue Insights Dashboard to show Commit + Closed Won

Tags: charts, crm-analytics

My manager wants to customize the standard Revenue Insights dashboard to show Closed Won + Commit amount on the chart which will show how close we are to quota with those two numbers combined. We are just learning Revenue Insights so not sure if this is even do-able in a standard dashboard or if we'd have to build something completely new. I did a little mockup to better illustrate what he wants to see.

[image]

Comment: I think I answered my own question...if we change our Forecast Rollups to cumulative, the Commit Forecast calculation will include both Commit and Closed Won, and be reflected accordingly on the line graph. But then this impacts how the data is displayed in the Forecasting app, so not sure what to do about that.